# How to stream AWS EC2 cloud-init logs to ELK?

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2, elk, cloud-init

My app dynamically creates EC2 instances via the AWS EC2 Javascript SDK. With each creation, a Bash script is run via the `UserData` parameter in the `runInstances` method. The logging for this Bash script appears in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` on the instance. Currently, I have to manually log in to the instance to review this file, which is tedious and not scalable.

How do I stream this logging to an outside destination? I want to use the [ELK](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/the-elk-stack/) stack, but the specific details of my logging solution probably aren't as important as just figuring out how to redirect the `cloud-init` logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with several methods.

---

#### Directly stream a log with Logstash

In this way, you need to install Logstash on your EC2 instances. But you can stream log to anywhere you want, such like Amazon ES, ElasticCloud or your own ElasticSearch host.

1. Install Logstash

- This can be done by either scripting in `UserData` or creating custom AMI with Logstash installed.
- Logstash is available via [binary file, package manager](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.9/installing-logstash.html) and [docker image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker.html).

2. Configure

- Logstash config file would be like:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/var/log/cloud-init-output.log"] # specify log file path here
  }
}

# if you need to process log on the fly
# you can use filter plugin
# filter {}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://YOUR_ES_HOST"]
    index => "YOUR_INDEX_NAME"
    user => "YOUR_USERNAME"
    password => "YOUR_PASSWORD"
  }
}
```

3. Start Logstash service

---

#### Use CloudWatch and Amazon ES

Less time for implementation but Amazon ES is required.

1. Push log to CloudWatch Logs with CloudWatch log agent.

- Configuration can be found in Logs Section on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html).
- Be sure to set `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` at `file_path` field.

2. Create ElasticSearch subscription filter in CloudWatch Logs.

- See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html).

---

Of course there are lots of way to archive that, these two are relatively simple imo.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) to stream logs to CloudWatch logs. From there you can [stream those logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html) to Elasticsearch. You would have to subscribe the logs and point it to your ELK stack.

Another possibly simpler solution would be using fluentd. You can use it to gather all the [local logs](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/syslog) and ship them directly to [Elasticsearch](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch).

Comment: The question as stated specifically seeks implementation details on how to hook ‘cloud-init’ logging to an outside resource, rather than just suggestions on what that outside resource might be.

Comment: Check out the links. They have all the details.

Comment: I actually looked at all of these links and tried them before posting the question. Couldn’t get ‘cloud-init’ in there.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you describe a specific scenario that didn't work, include the code you used, and results/logs of that.

Comment: There is no code to quote. As best I can tell, the Cloudwatch Agent does not connect to `cloud-init` specifically.